# Kafka log appender not available in kaa Admin UI

Tags: kaa

According to the Documentation (http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/Kafka-log-appender/ ) I can use Apache Kafka as a log appender in my application, but when I try to create a new log appender using the admin UI the Kafka type doesn't show up.

I'm using v0.10 Sandbox, deployed in a VM

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kafka Log Appender is missing in the Log Appender type drop-down for some Sandbox installations. This seems to be a bug and there is a ticket in Jira opened. See [KAA-1673](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1673).